# Python email lib - How to remove attachment from existing message?

Tags: python, email, mime

I have an email that I'm reading with the Python email lib that I need to modify the attachments of. The email Message class has the "attach" method, but does not have anything like "detach". How can I remove an attachment from a multipart message? If possible, I want to do this without recreating the message from scratch.

Essentially I want to:

1. Load the email
2. Remove the mime attachments
3. Add a new attachment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850757/python-eml-file-edit is basically the same question for Python 3.  I did not want to close it as a duplicate, as the answers here are either specific to Python 2 or vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`set_payload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.set_payload) may help.

> `set_payload(payload[, charset])`
>
> Set the entire message object’s payload to payload. It is the client’s responsibility to ensure the payload invariants.

A quick interactive example:

```
>>> from email import mime,message
>>> m1 = message.Message()
>>> t1=email.MIMEText.MIMEText('t1\r\n')
>>> print t1.as_string()
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

t1

>>> m1.attach(t1)
>>> m1.is_multipart()
True
>>> m1.get_payload()
[<email.mime.text.MIMEText instance at 0x00F585A8>]
>>> t2=email.MIMEText.MIMEText('t2\r\n')
>>> m1.set_payload([t2])
>>> print m1.get_payload()[0].as_string()
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

t2

>>>
```

Comment: Notice that the `email` API has been updated considerably in Python 3.6; you do not want to use the old API in new code any longer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, from my experience, in the context you are working, everything is a `Message` object. The message, its parts, attachments, everything. So, to accomplish what you want to do, you need to

1. parse the message using the [Parser](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) API (this will get you the root `Message` object)
2. Walk the structure, determining what you need and what you don't (using a method of a Message instance, - .walk()), - remember, that everything is a `Message`.
3. Attach whatever you need to attach to the parts you've extracted and you are good to go.

To reiterate, what you are working with is, essentially, a tree, where `Message` objects with .is_multipart() == True are nodes and `Message` objects with .is_multipart() == False are end-nodes (their payload is a string, not a bunch of `Message` objects).

Answer (score 3):

The way I've figured out to do it is:

1. Set the payload to an empty list with set_payload
2. Create the payload, and attach to the message.

Answer (score 1):

For MIMEMultipart you can attach, but you can't remove elements directly. Good news is that in this case get_payload() returns a standard python list of elements.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html

> Return the current payload, which will be a list of Message objects when is_multipart() is True, or a string when is_multipart() is False. If the payload is a list and you mutate the list object, you modify the message’s payload in place.

To clear entire MIMEMultipart payload just assign new empty list:

```
multipart_related.set_payload([])
```

This example removes only selected items from multipart/related payload list:

```
  for part in email.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'multipart/related':
      list_of_messages = part.get_payload()
      for message in list(list_of_messages):
        if message.get_content_type() != 'text/html' and message.get_content_type() != 'text/plain':
          list_of_messages.remove(part)
```